# How to reset Timer in react-Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to force the effect to re-run in order to start the interval again in React-hooks

here is complete code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-villani-8z938?file=/src/App.js

`const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);`

The reducer function x=>x+1 increments the timerReset value whenever dispatch  is called. And then I use timerReset to force the effect to re-run in order to start the interval again (if it stopped)

my time code is

````
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Timer({
  estimatedTime,
  onTick,
  active,
  newTime,
  timerReset
}) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(estimatedTime);
  const [counterSecond, setCounterSecond] = React.useState(newTime);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    let timersecond;
    if (active) {
      timersecond = setTimeout(() => setCounterSecond(counterSecond + 1), 1000);
      timer = counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    } else {
      onTick(counterSecond);
    }
    return () => {
      if (timer && timersecond) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        clearTimeout(timersecond);
      }
    };
  }, [counter, counterSecond, active, onTick, timerReset]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Time: {counterSecond} </div>
      <div>Countdown: {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem, 
`timerReset` should be a `boolean` and used within `useEffect`

```
  // App
  const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(p => !p, false);

  // Timer
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timerReset) {
      setCounterSecond(newTime);
      setCounter(estimatedTime);
    }
  }, [timerReset, newTime, estimatedTime]);
```

---

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState();
  const [activeAcounter, setActiveCounter] = React.useState(true);

  const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(p => !p, false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Active: {activeAcounter ? "true" : "false"}</h2>
      <h2>Time Reset: {timerReset ? "true" : "false"}</h2>
      <h3>Time: {counter}</h3>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveCounter(p => !p);
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          resetTimer();
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <Timer
        newTime={0}
        estimatedTime={60}
        onTick={setCounter}
        active={activeAcounter}
        timerReset={timerReset}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit quizzical-leaf-i30b3]

Comment: But now i am not able to capture the current time from your code

Comment: On button click it should pick the last time and reset it to.

Comment: "Reset it to" means `countdown === time` ?

Comment: Just explain in the question what the functionality should be...

Comment: On Submit function click Actually i was trying to first capture the time and then reset the timer

Comment: Don't know what "capture the time" means, but on submit you have the timer value, do whatever you want with it. `console.log(counter)`

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Vash

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little simplified solution without `useReducer`
App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Timer from "./Timer";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState();
  const [activeAcounter, setActiveCounter] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h3>Time: {counter}</h3>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveCounter(false);
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>

      <Timer
        newTime={0}
        estimatedTime={60}
        onTick={c => {
          setCounter(c);
          setActiveCounter(true);
        }}
        active={activeAcounter}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

timer.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Timer({ estimatedTime, onTick, active, newTime }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(estimatedTime);
  const [counterSecond, setCounterSecond] = React.useState(newTime);

  // Update time after each second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setCounterSecond(counterSecond + 1);
      setCounter(counter - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [counterSecond, counter]);

  // Reset time and countdown
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!active) {
      onTick(counterSecond);
      setCounter(estimatedTime);
      setCounterSecond(0);
    }
  }, [active]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Time: {counterSecond} </div>
      <div>Countdown: {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-worker-ege1k